# Is there some kind of blossoming towards the existentialist vision in French pre-Romantic poetry?

Tags: poetry, history-of-literature, french-language

I remember to have read somewhere, but, unfortunately, I don't remember where, that in certain pre-Romantic French poet one can find some kind of blossoming towards the existentialist vision.

Does anyone know something about this? If this is the case, who is the poet? Can you illustrate this idea with some examples?

Comment: I think I've finally found the text: "Rousseau, dans *Les Rêveries du promeneur solitaire* (1782), portera à son plus haut point cette tendance du siècle finissant, élevant le sensualisme de Condillac à un niveau existentiel (c’est le pur sentiment d’exister, et le bonheur qui l’accompagne, que cherche à retrouver le philosophe genevois)". From the book *Littérature: les mouvements et écoles littéraires* by Audrit and Gendrel.

Comment: That's not exactly poetry but, in a section called "Retour à la poésie" from another book I've found a similar idea.